# Changing the value of an std::variant with a subclass of the defined types

Tags: c++, c++17

Hi all I'm trying to implement a state machine in C++ using std::variant.

I'd like to return some event from my state update method which will be handled in the state machine to select a new state.

For the events I have a `base_event` class with for example a `event_x` and `event_y` subclass, which are used in a `std::variant<event_x, event_y>` and given to the state machine.

From the update methods I can not return a specific event type, that would defeat the purpose of the state machine, so I made the return type of it `base_event`.

Attached code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

class base {};

class derived_a : public base {};

class derived_b : public base {};

struct Visitor {
    void operator()(const derived_a& a) {
        std::cout << "a here\n";
    }

    void operator()(const derived_b& b) {
        std::cout << "b here\n";
    }
};

base some_fn() {
    return derived_b{};
}

int main() {
    Visitor visitor{};

    std::variant<derived_a, derived_b> variant;
    std::visit(visitor, variant);

    auto base_obj = some_fn();
    // Change variant to the value of base_obj

    std::visit(visitor, variant);

    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

So now my problem is that I can not turn the `base_obj` of type `base_event` into the variant to visit it with the visitor. Is this even possible in C++ or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Just return the variant instead? You most likely don't want to mix inheritance with variants because it's confusing, as can be seen.

Answer (score 1):

Setting variant with derived type calls correct callable

```
base *base_obj = new derived_b();
variant = *dynamic_cast<derived_b*>(base_obj);
std::visit(visitor, variant);
```

Below is the output after above

```
b here
```

Above solution will not work as derived type is unknown.

---

**Additionally**:
As std::variant works on irrelevant classes, for finite state machines it acts as an effective ***alternative to*** dynamic polymorphism as this avoids the strict interface requirements.

Pattern 1 (Sample Code):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

//some events : without dynamic polymorphism
class event_x{};
class event_y{}; 

//some states
class state_a{};
class state_b{};

struct transit {
    std::variant<state_a, state_b> operator()(const state_a& a, const event_x& x) {
        std::cout << "changing state a to b\n";
        return state_b{};
    }
    
    std::variant<state_a, state_b> operator()(const state_b& a, const event_y& y) {
        std::cout << "changing state b to a\n";
        return state_a{};
    }

    template<typename TState, typename TEvent>
    std::variant<state_a, state_b> operator()(const TState&, const TEvent&) {
        std::cout << "changing state * to a";
        return state_a{};
    }
};

class fsm {
    std::variant<state_a, state_b> m_state{state_a()};
public:
    void dispatch(const std::variant<event_x, event_y>& event) {
        m_state = std::visit(transit{}, m_state, event);
    }
};

int main() {
    fsm m{};
    m.dispatch(event_x{}); //prints changing state a to b
    m.dispatch(event_y{}); // prints changing state b to a
}
```

---

There are other patterns where only state are used as variant type.

Comment: Sadly I can not cast the type as I do not know to which type I need to cast. And in the pattern 1 example, what would the type of the void dispatch event be? In my case I would think that'd be the base class, but then I run into my problem

Comment: Inheritance use pointer semantic and variant use value semantic, this makes them difficult to use together.